# ASP.NET Core middleware with unbounded output

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a piece of ASP.NET Core middleware that produces an unbounded amount of data when it takes over processing a request. It goes into a loop that calls `await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync` as long as it is allowed to. If the caller stays connected, it expects to keep receiving data. This service is being hosted with Kestrel, and it seems to be working properly as described so far. But, what I am finding is that when the caller disconnects, Kestrel doesn't seem to notice and continues pumping output from the middleware. That output isn't going anywhere, because the memory usage of the process isn't going up, and at the same time `netstat -an` doesn't show the connection any more. But, the middleware just keeps on chugging away.

For typical HTTP requests, this wouldn't be a *terribly* serious issue, because most of the time the client doesn't disconnect when it has only read part of the request, and in those cases where it does, the response is finite in size anyway. But the pattern with this endpoint is that the data is conceptually infinite in length, and the caller stays connected for as long as it wants and then signals that it no longer wants further data by disconnecting.

These images illustrate the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw2iD.jpg

How can I make it so that the middleware notices when the client disconnects?

Comment: There's no way to determine this unless you have something else that is pinging the server from the browser to indicate it is still alive. This system you have here does seem quite odd though, and I'm not sure I would recommend it. Perhaps something like SignalR would be a better fit?

Comment: The program in question is a custom reverse proxy that filters requests before passing them on to another web server that is very picky. I am able to determine this because I wrote a monitoring mechanism to show what requests within the proxy are ongoing and how many bytes they have transferred. The target server is a webcam server with MJPEG streaming support, so when you browse to it, the client starts receiving a stream of indefinite length. While the tab is open, the stream shows as expected, but then when the tab is closed, the middleware keeps pumping data.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9Qp7VV3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this as an issue on the `aspnetcore` GitHub repo, and I got a reply that explained the problem and provided a solution:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22156

Basically, for better or worse, the ASP.NET Core infrastructure suppresses all errors from write operations, and so if the request has been aborted, calling `context.Response.Body.WriteAsync` fails silently. I personally think there's a mistake in there somewhere, but the rationale given is that this reduces exception/log spam from behaviours over which the server has no control.

Because of this, if you're writing a loop like mine, you have to explicitly check for the request having been aborted. The context provides a `CancellationToken` that is used to capture aborts. You can also use this `CancellationToken` on other actions the handler is doing that aren't within the scope of the request context.

My data pump looks like this now:

```cs
while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, context.RequestAborted);

    if (bytesRead < 0)
        throw new Exception("I/O error");
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        break;

    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    if (context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
        break;

    _statusConsoleSender.NotifyRequestProgress(requestID, bytesRead);
}
```